# Main method not found in class ActivityTime, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java

I tested my program on http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/roys-life-cycle/ . However, I always got Error: Main method not found in class ActivityTime, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)
This is my program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
* Created by DUY on 10/12/2014.
*/
class EatSleepCode {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int numberDay = 0;
        int numberMinuteOfDay = 18;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        numberDay = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        String[] str = new String[numberMinuteOfDay];

        for(int i = 0; i < numberDay; i++){
            str[i] = input.nextLine();
        }

        ActivityTime code = new ActivityTime(numberDay,str,'C');

        code.findLongestTime();
    }
} 

class ActivityTime{
    public int longestTimeOfDay;
    public int longestTimeOfTotal;
    public int numberDay;
    public String[] str;
    public char act;
    public ActivityTime(int numberDay, String[] str, char act){
        this.numberDay = numberDay;
        this.str = str;
        this.act = act;
    }
    public void findLongestTime(){
        int tmp1 = 0, tmp2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberDay; i++){
            tmp1 = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < str.length; j++){
                if(str[i].charAt(j) != act){
                    tmp1 = 0;
                    tmp2 = 0;
                }
                else {
                    tmp1 ++;
                    tmp2 ++;
                }
                if(tmp1 > longestTimeOfDay){
                    longestTimeOfDay = tmp1;
                }
                if(tmp2 > longestTimeOfTotal){
                    longestTimeOfTotal = tmp2;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(longestTimeOfDay + " " + longestTimeOfTotal );
    }
}
```

Can you help me solve this error? Thank you very much

Comment: Are u running the ActivityTime class rather than EatSleepCode? And what r u using, an IDE or commandLine ?

Comment: I believe class `EatSleepCode` needs to be declared `public`.

Comment: try to get the second class inherit to the first one.

Comment: @DrewKennedy The main class doesn't have to be `public`. (I wasn't sure, but I just tried it, and it works fine with default visibility.)

Comment: @chiastic-security I just tested it too and seems to be fine without it. Seemed like a good guess. :P

Comment: I have successfully tested on IntelliJ but I got error when testing on http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/roys-life-cycle/ @@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to separate these classes into two files, one called `EatSleepCode.java` and one called `ActivityTime.java`.

Once you've done that, you'll be clearer on which one you're running as your main class. It's `EatSleepCode` that has the `public static void main` in it, so presumably that is what you intend as your main class; `ActivityTime` doesn't have such a method, which is why you can't run that as your main class. That's what the error means that you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I tested my program on http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/roys-life-cycle/. This website don't allow upload two file. I can upload one file only. Can you help me this problem. Thank you

Comment: @RoboticVn In that case, you should make `ActivityTime` an inner class of `EatSleepCode`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested successfully. Thank you ^^